# Using jQuery POST in Wordpress with WooTheme's Canvas 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wordpress, post

All of my javascript and jQuery code is working except for `$.post`. I have tested posting directly to `http://MYSITE.com/functions/course-functions.php` via other means and gotten the following valid JSON response:

```
{"item":{"signedIn":true,"userID":"1","staySignedIn":"yes"}}
```

However, whenever I click the sign-in button the javascript/jQuery properly runs through the validation code, but then doesn't do the following code:

```
$.post("http://MYSITE.com/functions/course-functions.php", { 
  type: 'signIn', 
  email: email, 
  password: password, 
  staySignedIn: staySignedIn },
  function(data) {
    var response = data.item;
    console.log(response);
    if (response.SignedIn == false) {
      $('#alerts').html('Oops! The email and password you used did not work. Please try again.').show();
    }
    else {
      if (response.staySignedIn == 'yes') {
    localStorage.staySignedIn = 'yes';
    localStorage.userID = response.userID;
      }
      sessionStorage.userID = response.userID;
      sessionStorage.signedIn = 'true';
      var url = 'http://MYSITE.com/courses?userID=' + response.userID + autoClaimCodeURLvariable;
      window.location = url;
    }
  },'json');
```

I use the following wrapper to make jQuery ($) work in Wordpress:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //my jQuery Code
});
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this working? Thanks!

Comment: @ehmad11 I'm using the absolute URL, but it is all on the same domain.

Comment: In my PHP file, where the data is posted to I have the following code: `if ($_POST['type'] == 'signIn') { //code to execute}`. It also has `if ($_POST['type'] == 'signUp')`, etc. Not sure if `type` is a reserved word, but I tried changing `type` to `formType`, but the post function is still not working.

Comment: Apparently I have to create a workaround to use `$.post()` or `$.ajax()` in Wordpress. We'll see if I can get a solution working.